Prove there is simple cycle of length $1\leq k\leq n-1$ in $G_{2,n}$
I am trying to prove there is simple cycle of every length k for $0<k<n$ in $G_{2,n}$. $G_{2,n}$ is De Bruijn graph where the vertices are binary strings of length n-1 and the edges are strings of length n.$$$$
So far i could only prove for cases in which
n-1 divides k but i dont know how to proceed.
Any hints? Edit ( adding approach): If there exists c such that n-1=c•k then an appropriate vertex would be one that has a string copied c times, and the k steps will cut that string from the begenning and add it to the end resulting in the original string. Ofc we have to so that while making sure the cycle is simple.
Edit by Calvin: OP came up with an approach, but I mentioned in the comments that it didn't work, hence OP edited it away. I'm including this context to indicate that OP has made some attempts at the problem, and then realized that it didn't work hence removed it.

Sorry I misread. I thought it was of length $n+k$. $\quad$ Can you writeup your example? EG, In my read of it, for $n = 5, k = 4$, we start with $10101$ and then want to go to $01010$ and then to $10101$ and then to $01010$. But this is not a simple cycle as the vertices are duplicated. If so, then it only works for $k = 2$.

Your comment just made me realize the cycle in my example is actullay not simple.

an accurate example would be a cycle from $0^{n-1}$ to itself with k=1 for a step that is 0. Or for g2,3 a cycle that starts from 01 and does the steps 010 and 101 for k=2

Can you add your approach for when $k \mid n-1$?

If there exists c such that n-1=c•k then an appropriate vertex would be one that has a string copied c times, and the k steps will cut that string from the begenning and add it to the end resulting in the original string. Ofc we have to so that while making sure the cycle is simple.

Great, can you edit that into the problem statement to provide context? Otherwise it would seem like a "do not know how to proceed" question and might get closed. $\quad $ I've also updated my solution, and you can review that now.

Fix $m = n-1$, and $ k \leq m$. It might be easier to think of the equivalent formulation:
Find a sequence of $k$ 1's and 0's, labelled $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$.
Define $a_k+i = a_i$ for $ i \geq 1$.
Consider the $k$ strings of length $m$ of the form $b_i = \overline{a_i a_{i+1} \ldots a_{i+m-1}}$.
Then, $b_1, b_2, \ldots b_k$ is a cycle. (Why?)
Equivalent Problem: For this cycle to be simple, we require that these $k$ strings are distinct. What values of $a_i$ guarantees this?

 There are a few reasonable things to try, and hopefully you stumble on one that works.


 I didn't have to split into cases (though I can see why that could be helpful). Modify your $k \mid m$ example (in the comments) to work for $ k \not \mid m$.

Note

I'm using $m = n-1$ as I find it easier to think of binary strings of length $m$, than to carefully account for the difference each time.
Every $k$ cycle can be described in this manner, which is why it's an equivalent formulation. This might be hard to come up with independently, but should be obvious once stated, so bear it in mind for the future.
This approach can be extedned to the $ k > m$ case, but you have to be careful in checking the details. EG The construction (to the original problem) I'm thinking of works for $k=m+1$, but results in duplicates for $k=m+2$.
Bonus Problem: Solve this for $m+ 1 \leq k \leq 2m$ (which was my original interpretation).
Bonus Corollary: We have $\leq 2^k$ $k-$cycles (possibly self-intersecting). Can you give an exact count using Burnside's lemma? In fact, it's independent of $m$ which might seem surprising at first thought, but follows immediately from the above formulation.


Thank you, it will probably take me some time to undertsand it but i very much aprecciate your effort!!!
